# Prove that if $AB=BA$, ${\rm Ker}(A)={\rm Ker}(B)$, and $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB = BA$ and $\operatorname{Nul}(A) = \operatorname{Nul}(B)$, given that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues with corresponding eigenvectors, how can I show that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors? In other words, how do I prove that $B$ is diagonalizable? $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: What is $C$? Just some arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: Surely you mean $AB = BA$?

Comment: It's supposed to be AB=BA

Comment: You are presumably working in an $n$ dimensional space, also.

Comment: In general, matrices are not diagonalizable. For these matrices, the singular value decomposition is the closet form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with $\lambda$ being the eigenvalue.

If $\lambda = 0$, then $Av=0$. Since $Null(A)=Null(B)$, $Bv=0$ as well. Hence $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

If $\lambda \neq 0$,

$$A(Bv)=BAv=\lambda Bv$$

That is, if $Bv\neq 0$, then $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with $\lambda$ being the eigenvalue. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, $Bv=kv$. That is $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: For a critique see my Comment on the Question itself.

Comment: Hi, I think the question somehow has been through some changes, there was the assumption that the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: I was answeing the following question: If $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$  matrices such that $AB=BA$ and $Null(A)= Null(B)$, given that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues with corresponding eigenvectors, how can I show that $A$ and $B$
 have the same eigenvectors? In other words, how do I prove that $B$
 is diagonalizable?

Comment: The edit history is very strange.  As you understood, at one time the assumption was clearly stated (in English) that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, and then a Spanish version was introduced by the OP which obscured or removed that assumption.  I'm inclined to rollback the edits to the last point at which your Answer settles the problem.

Comment: I find it puzzling too. I wonder why Spanish version suddenly. Thanks for bringing this up.